# connection refused node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Helle every body i desired to test sockets,when i'm connected a alert should appear, it work on the computer where Node js is in installed but not in the other computer.

**The error :**

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>   http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: io is not defined

**the code :** 
    server:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs   = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
    fs.readFile('./index.html',function(err,content){
        res.end(content);
    });

}).listen(8080);

io = io.listen(server)

io.sockets.on('connection',function(client){

client.emit('connecte');

});
```

**client :**

```
<html>
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<head>
    <title>my first page</title>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>It work</h1>
</body>
<script>
var socket; 

socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

socket.on('connecte', function(){
        alert('You are connected');
    });

</script>
</html>
```

sorry for the language english is not my first language i try to learn.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Socket.IO docs](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-node-http-server) shows how to use Socket.IO with the built-in http server. Comparing that example and your code you can see you're not using `io` quite right. Try something like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, content) {
    res.end(content);
  });
});

io = io(server);

server.listen(8080);

io.on('connection', function(client) {
  client.emit('connected');
});
```

Also on an unrelated note, you could `pipe()` the html file to the client instead of buffering the entire file first:

```
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(res);
```